# Jquery selector .each()

Tags: jquery

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div id="myfavorites">
 <p><button id="saveFav">Save my favorites</button> </p>
 <p><a href="http://bit.ly/fzgxya">http://bit.ly/fzgxya</a> <a class="favlinks" href="#">(remove me)</a></p>
</div>
```

When button is pressed, I want to make a json object with all the links.

```
$('#saveFav').click(function() {
  var toSave = { "searchtext" : $('#searchText').val().trim() };
  var links = {};

  $('#myfavorites p').each(function(index) {
    links[index] = $(this).first('a').attr('href');
  });

  toSave.links = links;
}
```

But in $('#myfavorites p').each function, $(this) isn't the **p** element. I am missing something here. How can I iterate in all **p** and find the first **a** element?

And am I construction the object correctly? I mean if I pass it to a php page, will it json_decode correctly?

thanks

Comment: your function declaration inside `each` is missing an arg

Comment: where is your `$('#searchText')`

Comment: You have concluded that `$(this)` is not the `<p>` element, but I think it certainly is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try `find()` instead of `first()`:

```
links[index] = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

[first has no selector parameter](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: Actually it should be `.find('a').eq(0)` to mimic what the OP wanted "first()" to do

Comment: or links[index] = $(this).find('a').first().attr('href'); THANKS

Comment: find('a') works yet you still need to control if <p> contains a <a> in it. Otherwise you will have null values with in the links array. I don't know what does eq(0) does thou.

Comment: if <p> does not contain <a> `find('a')` will not find anything. `eq(0)` returns the first item from a result set

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $('#myfavorites p').each(function(key,value) {
    links[key] = $(value).first('a').attr('href');
  });
```

jquery each docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Comment: Using `this` inside an `each()` is the same as using `value`.

Answer (score 0):

[`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) does not work that way.  It takes a selector and returns the 1st from the list, and takes no arguments.

```
$('a', this).first().attr('href');
```

Or you can use the [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector.

```
$('a:first', this).attr('href');
```